# Do I run boot repair in secure or non secure mode?

Tags: grub2, boot-repair

Laptop starts directly in windows, Ubuntu 20.04 in boot menu disappeared
(no grub2 boot menu)

When I do a Boot repair, got this question :

The boot of your PC is in Secure mode. You may want to
retry after changing it to non-Secure mode
Are you sure you want to continue anyway ?

NO or YES ?

What do I answere ?

Comment: We can not decide that for you ;-)

Comment: Can it do harm to say yes and continue ?

Comment: You can try to boot both with and without secure mode. It may boot both ways, and it may boot only after turning off secure mode. It will ***not*** do any harm to try either way. - By the way, if your problems began after a [major] update of Windows, it might work to get into the UEFI/BIOS menu system, and change the boot order, so that Ubuntu will get on top. This means that you should get back the grub menu, where you can select Ubuntu (default) or Windows.